# Plot x and y if z == [value]

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Only just started using python this week, so I'm a total beginner. Imagine I have a massive dataset with data like so:

```
close    high    low     open    time      symbol
0.04951 0.04951 0.04951 0.04951 7/16/2010    BTC
0.08584 0.08585 0.05941 0.04951 7/17/2010    BTC
0.0808  0.09307 0.07723 0.08584 7/18/2010    ETH
```

How, using matplotlib, can I plot close with time, only if symbol = BTC? I was thinking something like

```
bitgroup = df.groupby('symbol')
if bitgroup == 'BTC':
  df(['close','time']).plot()
  plt.show()
```

Building on this, I'd then like to use these new groups to create new columns, such as returns, (calculated using (p1-p0)/p0) doing something like this:

```
def createnewcolumn()
   for i in bitgroup
     df[returns] = (bitgroup['close'].ix[i] - bitgroup['close'].ix[i-1]) / bitgroup['close'].ix[i-1]
createnewcolumn()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in turning this pseudocode into real code!

Answer (score 1):

```
df.symbol == 'BTC'
```

returns a list of `[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ... ]` for each row, and then you can use that as a mask on the original data -

```
df[df.symbol == 'BTC']
```

Comment: Taking your advice, I attempted to plot the data using                                                  df[df.Symbol == 'BTC'].plot(df['close'],df['time']), but it appears that it still attempts to plot all elements. Any further advice?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it -  df[df.Symbol == 'BTC'].plot(['time'],['close']). Now to figure out how to label the axis!